# Node DELETE function dosen't receive data

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Hello I have the following problem:

I try to build a node (express) REST API. Everything works fine so far but when I try to send data to my "DELETE" function the data doesn't arrive.

**Node**

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});
```

---

```
app.delete('/', function(req, res, next) {

    console.log(req.body.del); // output: undefind

    res.send("delete");
});
```

**Angular**

```
$scope.delete = function (del) {

    $scope.del = del;

    $http.delete( 'http://localhost:8080', {del: $scope.del } ).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            $log.log(data); // delete
            $log.log($scope.del); // correct value
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            $log.error(data);
        });
};
```

When I do it the same way with POST, everything works well. Also when I try it with curl everything works well.

```
curl --request DELETE --data "del=test" 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An HTTP `DELETE` method should not contain a request body and any information should be passed in the query string. Angular's `$http.delete` passes data as query parameters, not as part of the request body. You'll need to use `req.query.del` to access request parameters. With `curl` you're explicitly passing data in the request body.

To force Angular into passing the parameters as request body:

```
$http({url: 'http://localhost:8080', method: 'delete', data: {del: $scope.del}});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I use "req.query.del" it dosen't work even with curl.

Comment: `req.query` accesses parameters from the URL query string. Include the parameters in the URL when requesting with `curl`.